# how to split a dataframe to specific number of rows in if loop in R

Tags: r

I am writing a function to send emails to my clients in R. I am using mailR package to do so,but my service provider only allows me to send 100 emails an hour. What I want to do is, if suppose my email list contains 270 email addresses,I want to spilt that into `chunk1=100 , chunk2 = 100 & chunk3 = 70` Then it should send out emails to first chunk then wait for an hour and then chunk2 and so on. 
This is my function looks like.

```
email <- function(dataframe,city,date){
   dataframe$registrant_email <- tolower(dataframe$registrant_email)
   dataframe_city <- dataframe[dataframe$registrant_city == city & dataframe$create_date == date, ]
   # Removing NA's and blank email ids
   dataframe_city <- dataframe_city[!(is.na(dataframe_city$registrant_email)|dataframe_city$registrant_email==""), ]
   # Removing duplicate email ids
   dataframe_city <-dataframe_city[!duplicated(dataframe_city$registrant_email),]
   emails <- as.vector(dataframe_city$registrant_email)
   if(length(emails) > 100){

   # divide the vector into chunks of 100


   } else{send_email(emails}

  return(emails) 
}
```

I need a help in `if loop` how can I write the splitting part into chunk of 100 and then call a `send_email` function wait for an hour and so on.

Comment: To split a vector into chunks in a list, you can use something like `x <- 1:270; chunks <- split(x, (seq_along(x)-1) %/% 100)`

Comment: The use of `%/%` is beatiful, you should add it as an answer.

Comment: Could you explain the difference to my one-liner? The output seems to be the same. Does it account for some special case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your email-vector into a list with a one-liner:

```
mailinglist <- split(emails, ceiling(seq_along(emails)/100))
```

Then you could delay the execution of the mailing by something like:

```
for(i in mailinglist) {
 send_email(i)
 Sys.sleep(3600)}
```

I tested the loop with a simple `mean()` call and it worked, but you should test it yourself with a lower time and by sending mails to yourself.

Edit: To omit the delay on the last iteration, use this:

```
for(i in 1:length(mailinglist)) {
 if(i < length(mailinglist)) {
  send_email(mailinglist[[i]])
  Sys.sleep(3600)}
 else {
  send_email(mailinglist[[i]])}
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea. Perhaps OP could build the for loop in such a way that the `Sys.sleep` does not happen in the last loop iteration (where it's not necessary). If you like you can also add my `split` comment with `%/%` to your answer

Comment: How to build the for loop so that `Sys.sleep` does not not happen in last loop iteration

Comment: I asked above, could you explain the difference between our one-liners? The output seems to be the same, what does mine not account for?

Comment: @docendodiscimus Can you please tell me how can we avoid `sys.sleep` in last for loop ?

Comment: @Neil, after splitting and before the loop, you can check the length of the `mailinglist` and then inside the loop, check if your current iteration is the last (equal to the length of the list) and only if it is _not_ call the `Sys.sleep`, for example

Comment: @LeoP., I don't see what your split method doesn't account for in this scenario